# Hover effects on icon image?

Tags: html, css, hover, icons

I made a thread earlier about putting icons inline. But now, I'm having trouble trying to hover an icon image. For example, say I have a facebook icon, if the mouse is on this icon, I want this icon to bright a bit (not the background, just the icon) in order to indicate that the cursor is on the icon. From my memory, this was done through having two separate images (one with normal icon, the other being brighter than the normal icon) and you fiddle around with the background image within hover in css but I can't seem to work this out. In this example, say the facebook1.png is bright version and facebook.png is a normal one.

HTML

```
<a class="icons" href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
```

CSS

```
.icons a{

   display: inline-block;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}

 .icons a:hover {
   background: url(../images/facebook1.png);
 }
```

still can't seem to get this to work...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<a class="icons" href="http://www.facebook.com"></a>
```

And style as

```
<style>
.icons{
  background: url(../images/facebook.png);
   display: inline-block;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}

 a.icons:hover {
   background: url(../images/facebook1.png);
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Doesn't display anything :/ Don't I have to display something in the HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

First to the anchor that like following:

```
<a class="icons" href="http://www.facebook.com">f</a>
```

And change your css as following:

```
.icons {
   background: url(../images/facebook.png);
   display: inline-block;
   width: 64px;
   height: 64px;
   content:"";
}

.icons:hover {
   background: url(../images/facebook1.png);
}
```

This will change your background image.

Comment: Doesn't display anything :/ Don't I have to display something in the HTML code?

Comment: It displays but the hover effects doesn't work, do I have to put something inside the content:"";?

Comment: @user2320517 try with `background: url(../images/facebook1.png) !important;` in hover.

Comment: Still not working... is there something wrong with my code? the way I set up? and what does !important; do? thanks for trying to help btw :)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is using Javascript. Try using this code:

```
<script>
function changeImage()
{
element=document.getElementById('myimage')
if (element.src.match("fb_high"))
  {
  element.src="fb_low.gif";
  }
else
  {
  element.src="fb_high.gif";
  }
}
</script>

<img id="myimage" onhover="changeImage()"
src="fb_low.gif" width="#" height="#">
```

Just insert that into your code wherever you want and it should work. You can also do that with the Twitter icon, but you will need to have two separate pictures.

Comment: I'm trying this out, I'm not exactly sure how to use this - doesn't this mean I have to edit fb_high.gif and fb_low.gif for my files every single time? along with myImage to myImage1, myImage2 to add more (i.e. adding twitter icon as well, I have to put myImage2?)?

Comment: Well, I'll show you the website I got the idea from. If you read the surrounding paragraphs, it may make sense. The page is about changing HTML elements which is basically what you're looking for. Best of luck!
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp